# Tire sidewall damage from a pothole on the highway

Tags: tires, bmw, sidewall-damage, x1

[image]

I recently got a new car (bmw x1 2018) and couple nights ago, i hit a massive pothole on the high way. You should know that this is a leased vehicle and BMW wanted 2000+$ for rim and tire insurance but i decided to opt out of it since it seemed too much. They said the tires cost around 1000$ each as they are run flat tires. My question is, does this tire need replacing asap? I did not even know that my tires were in this condition until today.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the tire leaking air? Are there any bulges?

Comment: of all the damage to have on a sidewall, this one seems to have a spot of luck attached. It's the thickest part, there are no threads (ply) visible and no puncture.

Comment: No there isn't any leaking of air or bulges. @paulster2

Comment: Does that mean i won't have to replace them until i return the car back to bmw in 3yrs and half? @fred_dot_u

Comment: I'm a thrifty sort of person and would examine the tire on a daily basis, perhaps even more than once a day and check the air pressure at least weekly. If no obvious failure modes appear, you might make it through. Considering these are run-flats, they are engineered to remain on the rim when deflated. You seem to have all the odds in your favor. You may have to pay for replacement at the term end, though.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I will check on it on a daily basis and make sure no air is leaking. As for the rips on the top side, should i just leave that as is or get a rubber glue or just rip it off?? @fred_dot_u

Comment: I'll bet the small slice remaining will either remain or normal driving speeds will take care of the removal for you. It is something else you can watch, maybe make a mark at the current tear points and see if they advance over time.

Answer (score 1):

The rim does not look like a problem but you are going to need a tire , at least at the end of the lease. The rim can be sanded smooth and polished with various grades of silicon carbide sand paper . It will also need some paint or clear coat to look like original. I fixed much more damage in an aluminum Nissan rim because they wanted about $ 1000 for a new rim. However my rim was bent ( could not be seen by eye) and had to be replaced. I found a replacement on the net for less than $ 200.